# How to count and flag unique values in r dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

`data <- data.frame(week = c(rep("2014-01-06", 3), rep("2014-01-13", 3), rep("2014-01-20", 3)), values = c(1, 2, 3))`

```
         week values
1 2014-01-06      1
2 2014-01-06      2
3 2014-01-06      3
4 2014-01-13      1
5 2014-01-13      2
6 2014-01-13      3
7 2014-01-20      1
8 2014-01-20      2
9 2014-01-20      3
```

I'm wanting to create a column in `data` that counts the unique `week` and assigns it a sequential value, such that the df appears like this:

```
         week values seq_value
1 2014-01-06      1  1
2 2014-01-06      2  1
3 2014-01-06      3  1
4 2014-01-13      1  2
5 2014-01-13      2  2
6 2014-01-13      3  2
7 2014-01-20      1  3
8 2014-01-20      2  3
9 2014-01-20      3  3
```

Comment: `data$seq_value <- week(data$week)`, using `lubridate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `base R` by converting the "week" column to `factor` and specifying the levels as the `unique` values of "week".  Convert `factor` to `numeric` and get the numeric index of the levels.

```
 data$seq_value <- with(data, as.numeric(factor(week,levels=unique(week) )))
 data$seq_value
 #[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Or `match` the "week" column to `unique` values of that column to get the `numeric` index.

```
  with(data, match(week, unique(week)))
  #[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Or using `data.table`, by first converting `data.frame` to `data.table` (`setDT`) and then get the index values (`.GRP`) of grouping variable 'week'  and assign it to new column `seq_value`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(data)[,seq_value:=.GRP, week][]
```

Comment: hadn't used match before - great function... thanks!

Comment: Would you even need the levels argument at all? I think it could work well without it.

Comment: @gh0strider18, I like the options in akrun's answer, but you should be aware that they only work as expected if each week only has exactly _one_ unique date entry. If you had two different dates in the same week, it would label them separately. The same applies to the dplyr answer by DMC.

Comment: @docendodiscimus First i posted without the levels argument.  If the dataset is not in order, by converting to factor, i thought it would be safer to use levels.  Regarding the `week` column, yes, I did assume that there will be only a unique day within a week.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the idiomatic way would be just to calculate the actual week of the year out of the date provided (in case your weeks are not starting from the first week of the year).

```
as.integer(format(as.Date(data$week), "%W"))
## [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Another base R solution would be using `as.POSIXlt` class and utilizing its `yday` attribute

```
as.POSIXlt(data$week)$yday %/% 7 + 1
## [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

If you want a shorter syntax, `data.table` package (among many others - See @Kshashaas comment) offers a quick wrapper

```
library(data.table)
week(data$week)
## [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

The nicest thing about this package is that you can create columns by reference (similar to @akruns last solution, but probably more efficient because doesn't require the `by` argument)

```
setDT(data)[, seq_value := week(week)]
```

Comment: My understanding of the question is that they want what akrun's answer does i.e. start from 1 since they want to count unique weeks and starting the count at for example 5 could be confusing, IMO and IIUC. Your answer would be "wrong" if there were gaps in the weeks since they want to assign a "sequential" value and I think what they mean is a sequence without gaps.

Comment: But, still a nice answer, generally!

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(seq_value = dense_rank(week))
```

Comment: Wow - yes - this is very helpful - was not aware of the rank functions inside of `dplyr`